# Laravel Nova override vue component resulting [Vue warn]: Error compiling template

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-component, laravel-nova

I'd like to implement a user guide using this
https://github.com/shipshapecode/vue-shepherd
on my nova.

I changed a file **webpack.mix.js.dist to webpack.mix.js** (inside nova directory).

Then I did :

```
npm install
npm run watch
```

and made some changes in /nova/resources/js/views/index.vue
and also /nova/resources/js/components.js

/nova/resources/js/components.js

```
import VueShepherd from 'vue-shepherd'

Vue.use(VueShepherd)
```

/nova/resources/js/views/index.vue

```
 mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      const tour = this.$shepherd({
        useModalOverlay: true
      });
      console.log(tour);

      tour.addStep({
        attachTo: { element: this.$el, on: 'top' },
        text: 'Test'
      });

      tour.start();
    });
  },
```

Then I run

```
php artisan nova:publish
```

But now I got this error on my console
[image]

why it's happening and how to avoid that error?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have tag style in your svg, vue does not allow to use tags  and  inside , so,

1. remove tag  from your svg
2. or use it as